# How to dynamically chose PBS queues during job submission

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, job-scheduling, pbs

I run a lot of small computing jobs in remote cluster where job submission is managed by PBS. Normally in a PBS (bash) script I specify the queue that I would like to submit the job through the command

`#PBS -q <queue_name>`

The job queue that I need to chose depends on the load on a specific queue. Every time before I submit a job, I analyze this through the command on terminal

`qstat -q`

which provides me an output which looks like as follows

```
Queue            Memory CPU Time Walltime Node  Run Que Lm  State
---------------- ------ -------- -------- ----  --- --- --  -----
queue1           --      --    03:00:00   --    0   2 --   E R
queue2           --      --    06:00:00   --    8   6 --   E R
```

I would like to automate the queue selection by the job script based on two constraints

1. The queue selected must have a walltime more than the job time specified. The job time is specified through command `#PBS -l walltime=02:30:00`.
2. The queue must have the least no. of jobs in Que as shown in the above output.

I'm having trouble in identifying which tools that I need to use in terminal to help me automate the queue selection

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you could wrap your qsub submission in another script which would run qstat -q, parse the output, and then select the queue based on the walltime requested and how many active jobs are in each queue. The script could then submit the job and add `-q <name of desired queue>` to the end of the `qsub` command.

However, it seems that you are manually trying to do some of what a scheduler - with appropriate policies - does for you. Why do you need to dynamically switch queues? A better setup would be for the queues to essentially categorize the jobs - like you are already doing with walltime - and then allowing the scheduler to run the jobs appropriately. Any setup where a user needs to carefully select the queue seems a little suspect to me.